# Cake PHP parent/child/grandchildren menus

Tags: cakephp, menu

i want to display menus with their children and grand children
output will be like this

Parent

-child

-grandchildren

Parent 1

-child

heres my function in my MenuItemsController

```
public function buildTree($arr, $parent_id = 0) {
    $op=array();
    foreach ($arr as $item){
    if ($item['parent_id']== $parent_id){
                       $op[$item['id']]=array('name'=>$item['name'],'parent'=>$item['parent_id']
    );
            $children=buildtree($arr,$item['id']);
            if (children) {
            $op[$item['id']]['parent_id']  =$children;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

           }
          }
        }

        return $op;

    }
```

Heres on my View Element app\view\elements\navigation.ctp

```
<?php
    App::import('Controller', 'MenuItems');
    $menu_items = new MenuItemsController();

?>

<ul id="navigation">
<?php
foreach($mainMenuItems as $item) {
echo "<li>".$item['MenuItem']['name']."</li>";
$child=$menu_items->buildsubmenus($item['MenuItem']['id']);
            pr($child);
}

?>
</ul>
```

Comment: you're importing a controller into the view?!?!?! o_O .. yeah.. Who needs MVC anyway right?

Comment: how will you gonna approach it?

Comment: the controller should pass the data into the view, the view should be as clean as possible. If you need a function in your view you create a helper and if you need to call a function in the controller (but you shouldn't need to) you could use `requestAction()` in the view

Comment: can you help me out with it dude it drives me crazy coz im just new to cakephp

Answer (score 0):

Your controller needs to generate the tree and pass it to the view. How to generate it? it depends on your application, maybe you need to call the data base, maybe it's just a static array, etc.

You'll need to create your own format for the tree, for example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => child 11
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => grandchild 121
                    [1] => grandchild 122
                )

        )

    [1] => parent 2
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => child 31
        )

)
```

then you can pass it to the view and loop the array to create the menu. To do that , you could use a recursive function to display the array.. or if you know that there wont be more than 3 levels you could simply use 3 `for` loops

=) so this has nothing to do with cakephp.. however, if your menu is stored on the database, maybe you could use the [tree behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html) to retrieve the menu from the DB, however you'll still need to pass it to the view and create a function to display it

Hope this helps

Comment: yeah all my menus is from the database and it has no left and right fields